# Is there anything notable about this integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, approximation

**(Main question)**
I have an integral involving complex variables (but integrated on the real domain) that I need to evaluate numerically, but I am interested in knowing if it can be reduced to any given known form for which we have approximation schemes better than quadrature, which is what I am currently doing.

Here is the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{T} \left(c - iu \mathrm{e}^{-\eta(T - t)}\right)^{\alpha}dt$$

Notes on bounds on the parameters:

- $\alpha \in (0,1) \cup (1,2)$
- $c, \eta, T > 0$

**(Secondary question)**
I also suspect its conjugate is

$$\int_{0}^{T} \left(c + iu \mathrm{e}^{-\eta(T - t)}\right)^{\alpha}dt$$

But I also don't know how to prove it, because although the integrand is the conjugate, the same doesn't necessarily apply after integration, but my numerical experiments seem to indicate that it is.

Comment: Re your second question, it is always true as the real/imaginary part of an integral is the integral of the real/imaginary part

Comment: Of an integral of complex variables but integrated in the real domain, I assume? I guess I was confused because I know integrating in the complex domain does not preserve that property unless some boundedness conditions are satisfied.

Comment: You are raising a complex number to a non-integer power. That is not something which is universally defined. What definition are you using? It is always true that $\int_U \bar f = \overline{\int_U f}$, where $U$ is any space where integration is defined. What is possibly not true is whether $\left(\bar f\right)^\alpha = \overline{f^\alpha}$, as that can depend on how you are defining the exponentiation - usually defined by picking a branch of the logarithm.

Comment: I haven't had much thought about that part, because I have been doing these numerically. I assume it's the main branch of the complex logarithm. It's akin to when you write a formula with the real square root and you assume you want the positive answer.